# Core Data, can't save context

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm simply trying to save a ManagedObjectContext but while I get no errors, the fetched request returns the object with none of the saved values. Consider this simple example. You have a single object, you change a property and save it. The object is there but the property is not saved. As you can see, I want only one object, and the fetch returns this one object. BTW, the code is in a simple class, not the app delegate or a view controller.

Here is the sample code:

```
MyAppDelegate* delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext* context = delegate.managedObjectContext;

NSEntityDescription *myEntityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

[request setEntity:myEntityDesc];

NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
MyEntity* myEntity;

if (array == nil || [array count] < 1)
{
    myEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
}
else 
{
    myEntity = [array objectAtIndex:0];
}

myEntity.BoolValue = [NSNumber numberWithBool:someBoolValue];
myEntity.ID = @"Some ID";

if ([context save:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"no error");
}
else 
{
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"found core data error: %@", [error localizedDescription]]);
}
```

Here's the code used to retrieve the values later:

```
MyAppDelegate* delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext* context = delegate.managedObjectContext;

NSEntityDescription *MyEntityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

[request setEntity:MyEntityDesc];

NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

MyEntity* myEntity;

if (array == nil || [array count] < 1)
{
    //handle error
}
else 
{
    myEntity = [array objectAtIndex:0];
}

return [myEntity.BoolValue boolValue];
```

Comment: Can you verify your managed object context is not `nil`?

Comment: I put checks all over the place. Objects are still in scope.

Answer (score 0):

What does your `NSManagedObject` subclass look like?  Since the fetch is working correctly (i.e. returning the entity), I suspect something is wrong in the subclass implementation.

You should declare a `@property` for each of the attributes on your data model. And in the implementation file, instead of using `@synthesize` you need to use `@dynamic`.  Also make sure in your `xcdatamodel` that the entity has its class set, as well as the name.

```
@interface MyEntity : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * boolValue;

@end

@implementation MyEntity
@dynamic boolValue;

@end
```